# Last element doesn't include in variable by map from array

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

There is the problem with getting values from array by map.

I have Spreadsheet on this link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LfbrGvX-ObolRnbTjh0VWGci4QlFBzyKpL34i5_cA9Y/edit#gid=1550082939

Here there are two modules. The script in module globalVars works good, it's getting global variables and arrays.

```js
const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
let shSISTEM = ss.getSheetByName("@sistem");

// SETTINGS LIST NAMES ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  const rngSISNMS = [
      'RTSout',
      'CAFin',
      'CAFout',
      'RTSin',
      'NameJSONS',      
      'NameTable',      
  ];

/////////////////////////////////////////////

// ARRAYS OF SISTEM TABLES
  let [arrRTSout, arrCAFin, arrCAFout, arrRTSin, arrJSONS] = rngSISNMS.map(rangeName => {
    return shSISTEM.getRange(rangeName).getDataRegion().getValues();
  });
```

the problem is in module impJSONS with function jobForWork. I have there this script:

```js
function jobForWork(){

// Iamblichus code
  // const [nameJSON, turnON, nameTABLE, nameARR, nameDIR, idDIR] = arrJSONS[0].map((_, colIndex) => arrJSONS.map(row => row[colIndex]));

// my code
  for (var i = 0; i < arrJSONS.length; i ++){
    var j = 0;
    let [nameJSON, turnON, nameTABLE, nameARR, nameDIR, idDIR] = arrJSONS.map(() => {
      Logger.log(`element ${j}: ${arrJSONS[i][j]}`);
      let vOut = arrJSONS[i][j];
      j++;
      return vOut;
      });

    /// some opeartions with variables of i-elements in arrJSONS
    // ....outside functions with each i-elements
        if (nameJSON == "jobToRTS") start(nameDIR, idDIR);
        if (nameDIR == "IN_CAF") next(nameTABLE, nameARR);
        if (turnON) finish(nameJSON);
    /// ...

  }
}
```

The script works with array arrJSONS from table in "T:Y". It puts the elements from array to variables by arrJSONS.map, but it stops on element j = 4 and it's all. So the last element of array doesn't include in variable idDIR. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to iterate through `arrJSONS` and, for each iteration, you want to store each single value from the inner array in a different variable, [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) will suffice and you don't need `map`:

```
function jobForWork(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arrJSONS.length; i ++) {
    let [nameJSON, turnON, nameTABLE, nameARR, nameDIR, idDIR] = arrJSONS[i];
    // Do whatever you want with these variables
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. How must I include this in my code? If I change for on this, each variable takes all the array again...

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov No `for` is needed! You just need this line. Take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I tried it without "for" again. Just the same. Each variable took all the array. I need "for" as I think to use each variable at each iteration, I am planning to build few procedures for each step next...

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov `Each variable took all the array` This is possible. For example, with the code I provided, `nameJSON` will return an array with the 0-index of each inner array. With your current data, that is `[ 'INCL NAME', 'jobToRTS', 'jobToCAF', 'jobFromCAF', 'jobToRTS' ]`. If you are getting different results when logging `nameJSON`, you are not using the code I provided.

Comment: your code doesn't work I need. I need to put each element of array arrJSONS in different variable. Your code puts all the same array in each of 6 variables.

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov `Your code puts all the same array in each of 6 variables` This is not true. Either you're not using the exact same code I provided or you didn't check the results correctly. Each array is different in the sense that `nameJSON` includes all the 0-index elements, `turnON` all the 1-index elements, and so on. Can you share the code you're using right now? And how are you checking the results anyway?

Comment: I need different result. Look, I updated code in topic and wrote clarifications, where I need to work with each i-variable next in code...

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov I don't see any clarifications. Consider providing the expected outcome, if it's not the one I thought.

Comment: @ Iamblichus ok, here above I wrote some examples with function jobForWork

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov Alright, I see there was a misunderstanding. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ Iamblichus That's it!!!! thank you very much!!! good luck!!!)))